# Symfony 2.6 now fails to clear clear cache even when permissions are setup correctly

Tags: symfony, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, symfony-2.6

I have recently update my application to use symfony 2.6 and now I am getting errors clearing the dev and prod cache:

```
[RuntimeException]
Unable to write in the "/var/www/project/app/../var/cache/pro_" directory
```

or

```
[RuntimeException]
Unable to write in the "/var/www/project/app/../var/cache/de_" directory
```

However when the `pro_` or the `de_` folders dont exist the command runs just fine. I set up the folder using the ACL permissions:

```
HTTPDUSER=`ps aux | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1`
sudo setfacl -R -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX var/
sudo setfacl -dR -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX var/
```

Im also using the symfony 3.0 structure if that makes a difference.

**UPDATE:**

I have tried using the `umask(0000);` option and the command still fails. Same errors.

Any help or suggestions on what would be causing these commands to fail would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're digging into https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/12893

It seems you need to wait a bugfix or dowgrade on a 2.x directory structure.

Comment: good catch, i did a search yesterday for an issue on github but this one was created after that i guess. Ill just watch for updates there i guess. Thanks